# AWS GeoServer not responding

Tags: qgis, geoserver, amazon-web-services

I made a WMS host with AWS. The WMS work with link below

localhost:8080/geoserver/OSM/wms?

But I'd like to reach it out of the network with this link and QGIS:

http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/OSM/wms?

Failed to download capabilities

This is also not work:
http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you configure the firewall on the AWS VM?

Comment: Yes, I allow inbound traffic 8080 port.
I got timeout and sometimes http proxy error and refuse connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote Access Configuration

1. Open ports 8080 for remote GeoServer access on Windows Server:
   Windows Administrative Tools > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules > New Rule > Port TCP > 8080 > Allow > Domain/Private/Public > “8080 GeoServer”
2. Edit the line of C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.xx.0\etc\jetty-http.xml to allow access by all IP addresses (or whatever range that you want):

Note that before remote access through port 8080 is possible, this port must be configured in the EC2 Security Group settings, e.g.,

Custom TCP Rule     TCP    8080    0.0.0.0/0   Port for GeoServer

Comment: Any help how to write this parameters in jetty-http.xml "to allow access by all IP addresses"

Try to add this:

<Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
But not work.

Comment: Here is a document that I prepared for GeoServer 2.14 installation, iIt gives more detail on the configuration:

https://tinyurl.com/ydrnvqse

Comment: It's work, In the EC2 Network Interface preferences. I configured it with my parameters 8080 TCP and 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Good deal. Could you mark my comment as the answer to your question?

Comment: I done it 19 hours ago.